# Comparing 2 periodical lists and extracting new occurrences

Tags: python

I have periodical data coming in as list of unique `id`'s starting from latest occurrences.

**list1**

```
['001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
```

and `x` time later I get:

**list2**

```
['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '008', '007']
```

As you can see, in **list2**, new occurrences have moved to beginning, while old ones are pushed towards end.

What I want to do is to extract and append the `'006'` and `'004'` to **list3** resulting in:

**list3**

```
['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
```

I'm out of ideas how to do this, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure the new occurrences will always be at the first two indices of `list2`, then you can simply *slice* and then *extend* the slice:

```
list3 =  list2[:2]
list3.extend(list1)
print(list3)
# ['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
```

---

If you're not sure about the indices, then you can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to take all new occurences from `list2` and then *extend* with `list1`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

new_occurences = takewhile(lambda x: x!=list1[0], list2)
list3 = list(new_occurences)
list3.extend(list1)
print(list3)
# ['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
```

`takewhile` takes items from `list2` until the first item in `list1` is reached.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**

1. List items are unique
2. New items are pushed to the begining of the list

**Approach**

Find the first occurrence of the first item of first-list onto second-list and partition the second-list at the index of the occurrence. Combine the first fragment of the second-list with the first-list

**Code**

```
list1 = ['001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']

list2 = ['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '008', '007']

list2.index(list1[0])
Out[45]: 2

list2[:list2.index(list1[0])] + list1
Out[46]: ['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the number of new occurrences may be between 0 and n where n is the number of elements in list2. Similar in approach as @Abhijit but not as clean or efficient.

```
list1 = ['001', '003', '005', '002', '004', '006', '008', '007']
list2 = ['006', '004', '001', '003', '005', '002', '008', '007']

list3 = list(list2)
for id  in list2:
    if id == list1[0]:
        break
    list3.insert(0, id)


print(list3)
```